# Capacited Vehicle Routing Problem with flow formulations

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, vehicle-routing, network-flow

I'm trying to solve the CVRP based on flow-formulation. In such a model, we have a decision variable with two-index, $x_{ij}$, where I'm using the MTZ formula to eliminate sub-tours. We have then a continuous variable that represents the flow of the vehicle after visiting a customer. Let's say $y_i$. In the case of delivery, the constraints that I formulate is:

$y_j \le y_i - d_j*x_{ij}+ Q*(1-x_{ij})$  , where  $(0 \le y_i \le Q - d_i$).

For this example with $5$ customers : $\{1:19;2:30;3:16;4:23;5:11\}$ and $Q=35$, the solution I got is:

$x : \{(0,3);(3,1);(1,0);(0,2);(2,0);(0,4);(4,5);(5,0)\}$
For the other variables, $x$ is null.

$y: \{1:0;2:0;3:16;4:11;5:0\}$.
I expected 12 for $y_4 = 35 - 23 = 12$ and $y_5 = 12 - 11 = 1$

[image]

But something is wrong that I can not identify.

```
mdl = Model('CVRP2')
arc_k = {(i, j) for i in nodes for j in nodes if i != j}
var = {(i) for i in customers}
xt = mdl.addVars(arc_k, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name='xt')
y =  mdl.addVars(var, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, name='y')
mdl.modelSense = GRB.MINIMIZE
mdl.setObjective(grb.quicksum(time_truck[i][j] * xt[i, j] if i!=j else 0 
for i in nodes for j in nodes)) 
#Constraint 1- Exactly the total number of vehicles leaves and return to 
 the depot 
mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt[0, j] for j in customers) <= nT)
mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt[i, 0] for i in customers) <= nT)
# Constraint 2- Customer is only served once by only one vehicle
for j in customers:
    mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt[i, j] for i in nodes if i != j) == 1)
# Constraint 3- Only one vehicle enters and leaves each customer 
for j in customers:
    mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt[i, j] if i != j else 0 for i in nodes) - grb.quicksum(xt[j, i] if i != j else 0 for i in nodes) == 0)
# Constraint 4: Subtour Elimination 
for i in customers:
    for j in customers:
        if i != j:
            mdl.addConstr(y[j]<=y[i]-df.demand[j] + (truck_capacity) * 
           (1- xt[i, j]))
#Constraint 5: Capacity Bounding Constraint
for i in customers:
    mdl.addConstr(y[i] >=0)
    mdl.addConstr(y[i] <= truck_capacity - df.demand[i])
```

Comment: The question needs some clarification. You say you use MTZ to eliminate subtours, but your solution visits 0 (the depot?) repeatedly. So are subtours beginning and ending at 0 allowed? Second, is the vehicle picking up or dropping off at customers? One constraint suggests dropping off, but another suggests picking up. Finally, just to be clear, $y_i$ is the payload of the vehicle immediately after leaving $i$ (on its way to its next stop), as opposed to the payload on arrival at $i$?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to do the same model in this article for the case of delivery. The authors propose a model for collecting goods: https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/285563

Comment: if $x_{i,j}=1$ implies flow from node $i$ to $j$ then $y_i \lt y_j$ as per MTZ, so do your constraints enforce this?

Comment: If $x_ij=1$ then $y_j <=y_i$

Comment: @MAYA you may need to modify with $ y_j \le y_i -d_jx_{i,j} + Q(1-x_{i,j})$. That's what is given in the paper also. Otherwise either way $x=1/0$; $y_j \le y_i$ since $Q \gt d_j$

Comment: I edited my post. The problem that I can not understand why I got $y_4=11and y_5=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $y_i$ is the load in the vehicle when exiting customer $i$ (after dropping of $d_i$ units of goods there), then your first constraint has an incorrect middle term. It should be $$y_j \le y_i - d_j + Q(1 - x_{ij}).$$ This enforces the constraint $$x_{ij} = 1 \implies y_j <= y_i - d_j,$$ i.e., if the vehicle visits $j$ immediately after $i$ then the load when leaving $j$ is the load when leaving $i$ minus what is dropped off at $j.$

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I edited my post because it was not the correct formula. Using your formulas, which is the correct one, I got the solution presented in my post. The problem that why $y_4 = 11$. I except to have $y_4 = 12 (35 - 23)$ and then $y_5 = 12 - 11 = 1$ since the vehicle visits the customer 4 and then 5. Thank you

Comment: Your edited formula is still wrong. It has $d_i$ where it should have $d_j.$

Comment: Absolutely right, I edited my post. May be I can share the model in python to find out what’s wrong

Comment: I have just added the model in Python using Gurobi. The plot of the solution is the output of this model. But I can not figure out what I miss in the formulas. The value of $y_4$ is incorrect. Thank you

Comment: You appear to be assuming that the vehicle always leaves the depot with load $Q$ (35 in your example), but the model does not require that. Consider the final route $(0 \rightarrow 4 \rightarrow 5 \rightarrow 0).$ Combined demand at 4 and 5 is 23 + 11 = 34, so the vehicle can leave the depot with 34 units, drop 23 units at customer 4 $(y_4 = 34-23 = 11),$, drop the remaining units at customer 5 $(y_5 = 11 - 11 = 0)$ and return empty. What is the problem with that?

Comment: Indeed, I assume that my vehicle leave with a capacity 35 which is required in the model. 
So, there is no problem in the soultion. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your customers are $N =\{1,2,...5 \}$ while nodes $N+\{0\}$, subtour elimination constraint involves

$(3,1)$ and $(4,5)$
$y_1 + 16 \le y_3 \le 19 = (35-16)$ and
$y_5 + 11 \le y_4 \le 12$

$y_4 \le y_5 + 12$
since in your code you are still missing $x_{i,j}d_{j}$. you are using only $d_j$ which is still ok.

also all $y_s$ are bounded by $\{1:14, 2:5,3:19,4:12,5:24 \}$

Since the model sense is 'min' & thogh it applies to the objective value that doesn't include $y$ but since $y_5 =[0,1]$ solver chooses $y_5 = 0$ and that bounds $11 \le y_4 \le 12$, allowed min values for decision variables.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying me. Now I understand why I got this solution