# Capacited vehicle routing problem with heterogeneous fleet

Tags: python, gurobi, vehicle-routing

This question is related to this post where I was trying to understand how to formulate the CVRP based on flow formulation to eliminate sub-tours.

[Capacited Vehicle Routing Problem with flow formulations](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/11448/capacited-vehicle-routing-problem-with-flow-formulations/11452#11452)

Now, I'm trying to using different trucks. Basicaly, I suppose that I have two fleets with $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ as capacity where $Q_1 >= Q_2$ and $Q_1>= max\{demand_i|i \in customers\}$. So, I defined a subset of customers that the trucks with $Q_2$ can served. Let's assume: $customersD = \{demand_i <= Q_2 | i \in customers\}$. The problem that I got a disconnected cycle that I can't understand why (figure below). I use the same set of contraint for each type of fleet so I could not find where is the problem in my model (I'm using python with Gurobi).  Here is my code:

[image]

```
    arc_k = {(i, j) for i in nodes for j in nodes if i != j}
    var = {(i) for i in customers}
    const = {(i) for i in customersD}
    #---------------------------------------------------------
    xt1 = mdl.addVars(arc_k, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
    xt2 = mdl.addVars(arc_k, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
    y = mdl.addVars(var, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=0, ub=q1)
    z = mdl.addVars(const, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS,lb=0, ub=q2) 
    #------------------------------------------------------------------
    mdl.modelSense = GRB.MINIMIZE
    mdl.setObjective(grb.quicksum(time_truck1[i][j] * xt1[i, j] for i in nodes 
                    for j in nodes) + grb.quicksum(time_truck2[i][j] * xt2[i, j] 
                    for i in nodes for j in nodes))
    mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt1[0, j] for j in customers)  <= nT1, name='C11')
    mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt2[0, j] for j in customersD)  <= nT2, name='C12')
    mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt1[i, 0] for i in customers) <= nT1, name='C21')
    mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt2[i, 0] for i in customersD) <= nT2, name='C22')
    for j in customers:
            mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt1[i, j] for i in nodes if i != j) 
                          + grb.quicksum(xt2[i, j] for i in nodes if i != j) == 1, name='C3')
    for j in customers:
        mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt1[i, j] if i != j else 0 for i in nodes) 
                       - (grb.quicksum(xt1[j, i] if i != j else 0 for i in nodes)) == 0) 
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    for j in customersD:
        mdl.addConstr(grb.quicksum(xt2[i, j] if i != j else 0 for i in nodes) 
                       - (grb.quicksum(xt2[j, i] if i != j else 0 for i in nodes)) == 0) 
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    for i in customers:
        for j in customers:
            if i != j:  
                mdl.addConstr(y[j]<= y[i] - df.demand[j]*xt1[i,j] + q1 * (1- xt1[i, j]))
    for i in customersD:
        for j in customersD:
            if i != j:
                mdl.addConstr(z[j] <= z[i] - df.demand[j]*xt2[i,j] + q2 * (1 - xt2[i, j]))
    for i in customers:
        mdl.addConstr(y[i] >=0)
        mdl.addConstr(y[i] <= q1 - df.demand[i])
    for i in customersD:
        mdl.addConstr(z[i] >=0 )
        mdl.addConstr(z[i] <= q2 - df.demand[i])
```

Thank you for your help.